# Continuing music playback even while changing pages

Tags: html, backbone.js

[SoundCloud](http://soundcloud.com) is an amazing site that makes use of HTML5 and Backbone.js. The only thing is, I can't find what technology they use that allows the music to keep playing even while changing pages.

What technology are they using to get the audio stream playing?

Comment: I presume that it's a "single page app", which means that you never actually trigger a full page reload.

Comment: This is totally a legit question. I came here from searching for the answer to this specific question, and I got my answer.

Comment: interesting question, I dunno why they marked it "not constructive"

Comment: I rephrased the question a little to match Q&A format.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The fact is, that you do not load a new page, but the content is loaded via AJAX.

The page then uses the HTML5 History API to add the possibility to Navigate using the browser's backward and forward buttons.

I started into this topic by reading and trying out the following two resources:

http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html
http://html5demos.com/history

---

The most simple way is to load and replace the current content via AJAX and then call

```js
history.pushState(null, null, link.href);
```

In order to add the history entry of the currently shown page.

If you now press the back button, the browser won't load the previous page, but fire the event `popState`. This can be used to restore the previous page using AJAX or information stored in your JavaScript variables.

```js
window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e) {
    //loadPreviousPage();
}
```