# Keeping same div while browsing to other pages of a website

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

This question concerns the **Youtube** player found in the website [**orkut**](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orkut).

A cool feature about this player is that it starts playing a video and then when you browse to another page the video doesn't stop!

So it continues to play flawlessly without interruption.

Can anybody explain to me how this is achieved?

Is it because the same div is inside every page but that doesn't get reloaded when the page refreshes or when we go to another new link?

I know a bit of ajax but I have never used cookies! Are cookies used for this purpose?

Comment: Please use proper grammar and punctuation

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the url you will see that `orkut` is a single-page site (for the most part).

This means that if you click on a link, just another `div` will open (loaded with AJAX), but the complete page itself will not be reloaded.

The effect you are talking about is similar to the effect that [SoundCloud](https://soundcloud.com/) uses as well: music keeps playing while browsing to new 'pages'. If you want to implement this effect, I suggest you read the following (duplicate) question:

[Continuing music playback even while changing pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928994/how-to-keep-music-playing-even-page-switch-like-soundcloud-com)

Answer (score 0):

To explain this shortly
You have to engineer your application using **AJAX** , and write every action of user to **URL**.
So user can go back and forward using **browser buttons** but this will trigger your **AJAX** functions .

To do this you can use new **HTML5** feature **History API**, which unfortunately not available on browser such as IE even the newest version now IE 10.

This free chapter explain **History API**
[HTML5 History api](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html)

If you want to support all browser then i recommend you to use this javascript alternative
[history js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/)

Finally , this need a lot of work from your side , and if you wish to use easy way then use IFRAMES but i didn't recommend it never !