# Keep audio player loaded while changing pages, jQuery circle player

Tags: jquery, html

I have a jquery circle player that I want to stick to the top of my website. The problem is that when the user moves from one page to another, the audio stops playing because it is being reloaded.
Is it possible to keep my audio player "stuck" and loaded even when the user moves to another page in my site? I want something like a "fixed" div cross page without having to open a new page with a player in it. Don't know if that is possible or how difficult that would be.

Here is my player:

```
<div id="cp_container_1" class="cp-container" style="background:none;">
    <img id="bg_image" class="bg_image1 cp-play"  src="jQuery.jPlayer.2.2.0/v11/circle.skin/jplayer_bg_blue.png" />
    <img id="bg_image" class="bg_image1_5 cp-pause"  src="jQuery.jPlayer.2.2.0/v11/circle.skin/jplayer_bg_image_green.png" />
    <img  id="play_bg" src="jQuery.jPlayer.2.2.0/v11/circle.skin/jplayer_play_bg.png" height="57" width="56"  />
    <div class="cp-progress-holder"> 
        <div class="cp-progress-1"></div>
        <div class="cp-progress-2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="cp-circle-control"></div>
    <ul class="cp-controls">
        <li><a id="play1"  class="cp-play" tabindex="1">play</a></li>
        <li><a id="pause1"  class="cp-pause" style="display:none;" tabindex="1">pause</a></li> 
    </ul>
</div>  

var myCirclePlayer = new CirclePlayer("#jquery_jplayer_1",          
{
        mp3: "GotanProject_Triptico.mp3",
}, {
    supplied: "mp3",
    cssSelectorAncestor: "#cp_container_1",
    swfPath: "jQuery.jPlayer.2.2.0/v11/js",
    wmode: "window",
    play: function () {
        $(".bg_image1").attr("src", "jQuery.jPlayer.2.2.0/v11/circle.skin/jplayer_bg_image_green.png");
    },
    pause: function () {
        $(".bg_image1").attr("src", "jQuery.jPlayer.2.2.0/v11/circle.skin/jplayer_bg_blue.png");
    },
    ended: function () {
        $(".bg_image1").attr("src", "jQuery.jPlayer.2.2.0/v11/circle.skin/jplayer_bg_blue.png");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you would use AJAX for something like that and just load the content.
Have a look at this question and answer:

[Continuing music playback even while changing pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928994/how-to-keep-music-playing-even-page-switch-like-soundcloud-com)

I hope this helps,
Tom